# How to properly rig character with bones in the Pose mode, while Boolean modifier is on?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, pose-mode, boolean-modifier

For example, I have a mesh of a larger ball and a mesh of a smaller cone, then use a Boolean modifier to find the difference between the ball and the cone. The result is that the ball surface has a cut by the cone. The Boolean modifier is kept active on the ball without applying.

[image]

Now, bones are added. My plan is to parent the ball and the cone to the bone, so that the ball (with that cut) can move or rotate depending on the motion of the bone.

[image]

However, the problem is that when the ball is rotated as I rotate the bone, the shape of the cut begins to deform in the *Pose mode*.

[image]

How do I keep the shape of the cut unchanged when the ball is rotated by using the bone in the *Pose mode*?

One obvious way to solve this problem is to apply the Boolean modifier before rigging. However, applying the Boolean modifier is destructive and may cause some unexpected problems in the uncertain future.

[image]

Comment: What kind of issue do you expect? Usually you rig a final object. You can always keep a copy of the blend file with just the model with all its modifiers that compose it, but when it comes to rigging you most often want the simplest and most stable asset you can. Having all sorts of unapplied modifiers just for the sake of being nondestructive doesn't help you there, it's actually making things unreliable, and on a larger scale impact performances drastically.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! The modifiers are not applied because the shape of my model is not finalized. In addition, I also asked ChatGPT, who recommended me to keep the Boolean modifier active when rigging.

Comment: Yeah... I wouldn't listen to ChatGPT too much. You shouldn't rig an unfinished model in the first place.

Comment: @L0Lock  The modelling process can not be finished without carefully observing the model in variously different poses. The shape of the model may look good in one specific pose, but may look awful in another pose. Modelling in variously different poses requires rigging. That is why I have to rig an unfinished model, otherwise modelling can not be finished.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I have just found a quick solution to this. I just move the Boolean modifier below the Armature modifier, then the problem is solved so far. However, I am not sure whether this is the ultimate solution without causing any future issue or not.

[image]